# Updating RESTful resources against aggregate roots only

Tags: json, web-services, rest, http, restful-architecture

Usually I architect RESTful APIs using the following resource URI scheme:

```
POST /products
PATCH /products/{id}
GET /products
GET /products/{id}
DELETE /products/{id}
```

Products may also contain *product features*. When I want to get some product's features, I would perform a `GET /products/{id}/features`.

BTW, if I want to add new features to a given product, usually I don't provide a resource URI like this: `PATCH /products/{id}/features` but I consider that `features` are part of a given product, thus, I update which features might contain a feature as follows:

```
PATCH /products/{id}

{
    "features": {
         "add": [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

In the other hand, if I want to update some feature metadata I wouldn't use the *product resource* but I would perform a request like this:

```
PATCH /products/features/{id}

{
    title: "Test"
}
```

In my case, *product features* are unrelated to a particular product, but they can be associated to many products.

Ideally, I should update which features own a given product issuing a `PATCH` request to `/products/{id}/features`, BTW it overcomplicates the server API because you need to cover all entity's aggregates separately.

My concern is if it's fine to consider that some given aggregate root's associations are updatable as part of the entity itself.

### More background on the topic

At the end of the day, one might say that an API like this isn't fully RESTful, because I shouldn't expect to remove features from some given product using `PATCH` verb but `DELETE`: `DELETE /products/{id}/features/{featureId}`, which turns the API usage from the client point of view easier than patching the product with a *DTO*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your architecture isn't perfectly clean. In part, you implement restful way of thinking, but on the other hand, things like

> ```
> PATCH /products/{id}
>
> {
>     "features": {
>          "add": [1, 2, 3]
>     }
> }
> ```

or

> ```
> PATCH /products/features/{id}
>
> {
>     title: "Test"
> }
> ```

are unintuitive.

For the first example, I would recommend

```
PATCH /products/{id}

{
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

where you provide **all** features for this product. You can't just define your own element `add`, which adds given features to the product. Structure of the updating resource should be comparable to structure you get with `GET /products/{id}` (I guess you don't get `add` attribute, do you?).

For the second one, your url should be sth like `/product-features/{feature_id}` or just `/features/{feature_id}`. Don't break the pattern `/products/{product_id}` with `/products/features/{feature_id}`. Why should you think this way? It's logical - when you `GET /products`, you don't get resource with list of all features

```
{
    ...
    "features": [
        {
             "id": 1
        },
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

but instead of, a list of all products

```
{
     [
          {
               ....
               "id": 1,
               "features": ...
          },
          ...
     ]
}
```

Answering to your question, if you implement it properly as I suggested in a restful way, updating product's features is absolutely okay this method.

---

**Edit:**

> About the thing of /products/features or /product-features, is there
> any consensus on this? Do you know any good source to ensure that it's
> not just a matter of taste?

I think this is misleading. I would expect to get all features in all products rather than get all possible features. But, to be honest, it’s hard to find any source talking directly about this problem, but there is a bunch of articles where people don’t try to create nested resources like /products/features, but do this [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150218/rest-collections-good-practice-to-do-get-api-collectiona-collection-id-colle).

> About the thing of add when patching, it's the easiest way I've found
> to express that I'm adding, updating or removing features from a given
> product. In fact, it's a DTO

If you want to use some actions on collections, there is a standard for it. Just take a look at [Best practice to batch update a collection in a REST Api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597768/best-practice-to-batch-update-a-collection-in-a-rest-api-call)
and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.2. Instead of

```
PATCH /products/{id}

{
    "features": {
         "add": [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

you will send

```
PATCH /products/{id}

{
    "op": add, "path": "/features/0", "value": 1,
    "op": add, "path": "/features/0", "value": 2,
    "op": add, "path": "/features/0", "value": 3
}
```

> BTW, note that you didn't answer the core issue in my question.

As [everything can be considered as sub-resource](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308349/rest-api-handling-subresources), I don't see any conflict if product's features, as a collection, is an attribute of the product and also it's considered as sub-resource to enable POST for example. If one's find it not safe, then you can [cut it to operate](https://www.pragmaticapi.com/blog/2013/03/25/extend-your-crud-http-api-with-sub-resources/) only on sub-resource.

Moreover, in this [article](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) author approved the way of updating sub-resources with PATCH do simplify the process (the whole article is a little bit controversial but it's not over the thing we are interested)

> Another solution is to expose the resource’s properties you want to
> make editable, and use the PUT method to send an updated value. In the
> example below, the email property of user 123 is exposed:
>
> ```
> PUT /users/123/email
>  
> new.email@example.org
> ```
>
> While it makes things clear, and it looks like a nice way to decide
> what to expose and what not to expose, this solution introduces a lot
> of complexity into your API (more actions in the controllers, routing
> definition, documentation, etc.). However, it is REST compliant, and a
> not-so-bad solution, but there is a better alternative: PATCH

Comment: Hey, thank you for your effort. Let's discuss some points. About the thing of `/products/features` or `/product-features`, is there any consensus on this? Do you know any good source to ensure that it's not just a matter of taste? From my point of view, `features` are of `products` domain, thus, the URI emphatizes this more than `product-features`. I understand that *all products* can work with *all features*. Thus, `features` are nested on `products`. This is my reasoning. It would be really nice if you know any resource I could check and get further thoughts on this concrete topic.

Comment: About the thing of `add` when *patching*, it's the easiest way I've found to express that I'm *adding*, *updating* or *removing* features from a given product. In fact, it's a DTO as defined [here (disclamer: I'm the owner of the whole site)](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/create-update-delete-collection). At the end of the day, my project requires to add, delete or update features in a single batch. Therefore, pure RESTful approach wouldn't be a good idea. For example, I could do a batch delete as follows: `DELETE /product/features/1,2,3`

Comment: But I can't do a delete, patch and post against using a single request. That's why I've ended up with `{ "whatever": { "add": [], "update": [], "delete": [] } }`.

Comment: BTW, note that you didn't answer the core issue in my question. My concerns goes on the choice of working against an aggregate root represented by a given resource URI, and decide if its aggregates have their own sub-resources or they should be worked out as part of the aggregate root

Comment: Well, you give a conclusion, but it would be very interesting that you could provide more background on *why is correct* and links to external resources or even other Q&As where me and future readers could find the key point to decide what's right or wrong :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Hello buddy, thanks for comments, I just updated the answer and I look forward to hearing your opinions :)

Comment: Now I believe that your answer is complete. As of the thing of `product-features` vs `products/features`, your argument is very solid. I'm going to stick with it. And about the thing of batch patching, at least I feel I got to the same conclusion with a different JSON schema, and the standard way use URIs instead of object identifiers which seems more convenient compared to my approach.

Comment: In summary, thank you for your great effort. I feel that it'll be very useful for future readers, we both introduced a good discussion and conclusions :)