# Converting resources in a RESTful manner

Tags: rest, design-patterns, transactions

I'm currently stuck with designing my endpoints in a way so that they are conform with the REST principles but also ensure the integrity of the underlying data.

I have two resources, `ShadowUser` and `RealUser` whereas the first one only has a first name, last name and an e-mail. 
The second user has much more properties such like an Id under which the real user can be addressed at other place in the system.

My use-case it to convert specific `ShadowUser`s into real users.

In my head the flow seems pretty simple:

- get the shadow users /GET api/ShadowUsers?somePropery=someValue
- create new real users with the data fetched /POST api/RealUsers
- delete the shadow-users /DELETE api/ShadowUSers?somePropery=someValue

But what happens when there is a problem between the creation of new users and the deletion of the shadow ones? The data would now be inconsistent.
The example is even easier when there is only one single user, but the issue stays the same as there could be something between step 2 and 3 leaving the user existing as shadow and real.

So the question is, how this can be done in a "transactional" manner where anything is good and persisted or something went wrong and nothing has been changed in the underlying data-store?

Are there any "best practices" or "design-patterns" which can be used?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the role of the RESTful API GETting and POSTing those real users in batch (I asked a question some weeks ago about a related issue: [Updating RESTful resources against aggregate roots only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739067/updating-restful-resources-against-aggregate-roots-only)).

In the API side, POSTed users wouldn't be handled directly but they would be enqueued in a reliable messaging queue (for example [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)). A background process would be subscribed to the whole queue and it would process both the creation and removal of real and shadow users respectively.

The point of using a reliable messaging system is that you can implement retry policies. If the operation is interrupted in the middle of finishing its work, you can retry it and detect which changes are still pending to complete the task.

In summary, using this approach you can implement that operation in a transactional way.